# Small voltage reading between Spa water and earth ground

Tags: voltage

I've noticed a strange voltage reading between the water in my spa and natural earth ground. The reading varies between .35VAC and .7VAC. My wife noticed a small shock from the water after inserting her finger in the spa while standing outside the spa.

The strange thing is that the voltage is still present after shutting off the breaker to the spa, and the main house breaker. With the power shut-off to the entire house, and there's no other power source anywhere in my yard, I'm assuming I'm picking up stray voltage from buried lines or possibly the neighbor's home?

The voltage reading is 0VAC when reading from the spa water to ground bar at the main spa panel.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is the spa circuit protected by a GFCI?

Comment: If I recall my Portal 2, that's about the voltage of a potato battery.  Is it AC or DC?  You have to test either one separately.

Comment: Do you know how the equipotential bonding for the spa was constructed?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this fits, but, we ran into similar situation with a bath tub. We went so far as to pull the electric meter on the house and still had voltage reading. Turned out to be ground wires had been stolen from the electric service poles for some distance.